# Allocating more disk space to Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, disk-usage

I used the windows installer to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC. By default it was installed with 17 gigs of space. I have filled up this space and want more. Is there any way to allocate more disk space to Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you set it up to dual-boot, or did you use WUBI?  The former has Ubuntu using a separate partition, while the latter has Ubuntu running within Windows, like an application.

Comment: The question seems to indicate he used WUBI.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is a way to allocate more disk space for Ubuntu. Place your Live Cd into your CD/DVD drive boot from it until you reach the desktop. Now load up Gparted. this is a partition manager. you will see your partitions on your HD. Ok now move your mouse over to the windows partition and resize it. No biggie eh? You now have more Linux room. Just one more thing I would ask are you using this extra room for data or a swap file? if so you might want to make this extra room as a data partition so that it can be accessed by both Windows and Linux that way neither OP system loses the HD space.... Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boo-table hard drive partitioning tool such as paragon , which allow you to resize your partition without data corruption.